# Prevent application switch when receive a broadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm using a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen for a service from a hidden application. When I receive the broadcast message from the hidden application it goes to first plan making the receiver application go to background. How can I prevent this behavior?

**EDIT 1**

```
   private void ExecBarcode()
    {
        final TextView barcodeResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txvBarcodeResult);

        BroadcastReceiver actionBarcodeScannerAndPresenceReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            /*  Receiver for the barcode scan and presence sensor events    */
                if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION_PRESENCE)) {
                    try
                    {
                        Log.e("Sensor Presenca","Detectada");
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ocorreu um erro no sensor de presença", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION_ON_BARCODE)) {
                    try {
                        String scannedText = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.BARCODE_TEXT);
                        barcodeResult.setText(scannedText);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ocorreu um erro ao ler o código de barras!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        };

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(Constants.ACTION_ON_BARCODE);
        filter.addAction(Constants.ACTION_PRESENCE);
        registerReceiver(actionBarcodeScannerAndPresenceReceiver, filter);
    }
```

The code above, is used to receive the broadcast event. The application that broadcast the message is running in background when the message is transmitted.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating your problem. Normally, receiving a broadcast does not affect the UI of the app.

Comment: Try registering your receiver in the manifest, instead of from your activity.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is possible register an variable receiver? Or I need to create a broadcastreceiver class?

Comment: You would need to create a subclass of `BroadcastReceiver`.